# FHIR Action names

Tags: hl7-fhir

The spec is ambiguous on resource actions. In REST details an underscore is prefixed to the action name, such as _history or _search. However the summary section is without the underscores.

What is the correct name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_history. I overlooked the bottom section - it will be updated shortly. Sorry

Comment: No worries, just wanted to make sure.